Wordpress shortcode to get service prices from database effectively
I want to display service prices dynamically in my HTML. I have prices in MySQL db. I have created shortcode to get each service price individually, so if I have 10 services(i display some of them multiple time) I need to make many SQL queries. How can I make it faster and reduce load on DB?
This is my shortcode
function get_service_price($atts) { 

    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'service_name' => '',
        'location_id' => '',
        'vehicle_id' => ''
    ), $atts);

    $service_name = $a['service_name'];
    $location_id = $a['location_id'];
    $vehicle_id = $a['vehicle_id'];

    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT price FROM {$wpdb->prefix}services WHERE service_id = %s AND location_id = %s AND vehicle_id = %s",
        $service_name,$location_id,$vehicle_id
    ));

    return esc_html($result->price)."€";
}


One thing you could do is to use wp_cache_set() and wp_cache_get() to cache the data for a fixed amount of time (eg. one minute) which will in turn reduce the number of times you run your custom query on page load and thus improve performance at the same time.
For example:
function get_service_price($atts) { 

    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'service_name' => '',
        'location_id' => '',
        'vehicle_id' => ''
    ), $atts);

    /** Generate an unique key for this request */
    $cache_key = 'service_price_' . md5( json_encode($a) );

    /**
     * Check whether we have cached data for this request.
     *
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_get/
     */
    $price = wp_cache_get( $cache_key );

    if ( false === $price ) {
        $service_name = $a['service_name'];
        $location_id = $a['location_id'];
        $vehicle_id = $a['vehicle_id'];

        global $wpdb;

        $result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT price FROM {$wpdb->prefix}services WHERE service_id = %s AND location_id = %s AND vehicle_id = %s",
            $service_name,$location_id,$vehicle_id
        ));

        $price = $result->price;

        /**
         * Store this data in cache.
         *
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_set/
         * @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants
         */
        wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $price, '', MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ); // Store in cache for one minute
    }

    return esc_html($price)."€";
}

This is just a POC and there's room for improvement but should give you at least a good idea of what can be done to improve your shortcode's performance.
